# How to JIT compile a standalone Angular component with external modules?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to load custom HTML into a dynamic component in `Angular v17`. It works in development mode, but breaks when built for production. Created a new application with `ng new angular17 --minimal`. The source is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/csgulyas/angular17-jit-component). (**NodeJS v18.13.0** is a minimum requirement.)

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ɵglobal } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { NzSwitchModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/switch';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, NzSwitchModule],
  template: `
    <h2>Expected</h2>
    <nz-switch></nz-switch> {{ text }}
    <h2>Actual</h2>
    <ng-container #container></ng-container>
  `,
  styles: [],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container!: ViewContainerRef;
  text = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const html = `<nz-switch></nz-switch> {{ text }}`;
    const parent = this;
    
    import('@angular/compiler').then((compiler) => {
      compiler.publishFacade(ɵglobal);

      const dynamicComponent = Component({template: html, jit: true, standalone: true, imports: [NzSwitchModule]})(class { text = parent.text;});
      this.container.createComponent(dynamicComponent);
    });
  }
}
```

I picked `NzSwitchModule` from [NG Zorro component library](https://ng.ant.design/components/switch/en) as an external module, just because I use it in my projects.

If I run the project in development mode, aka `npm start`, the expected and actual match.

[image: Served application correctly showing NG Zorro switch component]

However, if I build the application `npm run build`, and run it through some means of web hosting, for example `npx http-server .\dist\angular17\browser\`, the switch component is not visible.

[image: Build application missing NG Zorro switch component]

This dynamic component composition did not work at all in previous versions of Angular. I have a feeling that it has something to do with Vite and ESbuild in Angular v17, but I'm not very familiar yet with this new version.

I'm aware that I can set `aot: false` in angular.json under production configuration, but I'd like to avoid it if possible.